# What happens when you roll a critical on both advantage dice?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, critical-hit, advantage-and-disadvantage

What happens if you have an advantage on attack and you get 20 on both rolls. Does it differ from regular critical or not?

For example:
- on virtual table, like roll20 when you score two criticals, there are two rolls for critical damage.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for the downvotes? Please explain why you felt it was not a good question

Comment: @PremierBromanov Downvotes on short rules questions tend to mean “this has a trivial/obvious answer found by reading the rule again.” That would fit in this case.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## There Is No Difference

> When [you have advantage], you roll a second d20 when you make the roll. Use the higher of the two rolls… (PH 173).

Even though you're rolling two dice, you are only using *one* of them, and thus it's a normal, everyday, vanilla critical hit.

Comment: But you should take special note of the second die--it's clearly an overachiever.